# Can I change/modify a Windows PC Files Fromm my Raspberry Pi 3? If I can, then how?

Tags: pi-3, networking, windows

So I have a raspberry pi 3 which is running the software it is supposed to run... I now want to view the files of my windows pc on my raspberry pi 3 through network (they are on the same network). I have a shared folder on my windows pc. I tried, and I can access the files, but cannot modify them, only read. I want not only to be able to read but also to be able to modify them, or modify the particular folder. I am a total noob at this so please specify what I have to do. Please tell me from the starting. I am running windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Your question is about Windows access rights.

Comment: If you had made a shared folder on the RasPi that other network devices can connect to, then it would be a question for Raspberry Pi. So it is not.

Comment: It i s a question about the pi. I want to access my windows files from my pi and edit them. I just want to know that how to do that.